# grep with filter grep, how?

Tags: grep, filter

All I need is the Zip file name.
In the first step I searched for the author:

```
egrep -ni -B1 --color "$autor: test_autor" file_search_v1.log > result1.log
```

whatever worked, the result was:

> zip: /var/www/dir_de/html/dir1/dir2/7890971.zip
>   author: test_autor
>   zip: /var/www/dir_de/html/dir1/dir2/10567581.zip
>   author: test_autor

But, as mentioned above, the Ziip file name.
In the second step I tried to filter the result of the first search again:

```
egrep -ni -B1 --color "$autor: test_autor" file_search_v1.log | xargs grep -i -o "\/[[:digit:]]]\.zip"
```

to search only for the filename, unfortunately this does not work.

My question.
How should the second grep filter "look" so that I only get the zip file name?

Comment: Could you please paste a few lines of `file_search_v1.log` so we know what the original file looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -B1 "$autor: test_autor" file_search_v1.log | grep -o "[^/]*\.zip$"
```

Change the first `grep` as needed. The second `grep` filters out the parts at the end of the line containing non-`/` characters followed by the `.zip` suffix.

If you know that your zip files only contains digits, you could exchange `[^/]` with `[[:digit:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

With single **`awk`** expression:

```
$ author="test_autor"
$ awk -v pat="author: $author" '$0 ~ pat{ sub(/^.*\//, "", zip); print zip }{ zip=$0 }' file
7890971.zip
10567581.zip
```